Flask: cannot curl it from docker container
Have 2 applications:

Inside docker container
Python Flask as http://localhost:5000. 1st application should call
Python Flask.

Yes, I know that localhost unreachable from docker container. To get localhost, I put the following lines in docker-compose.yml:
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

Check availability of localhost from docker container:
vbulash@vbulash-notebook:~/VSCode/device$ docker compose exec app_device bash
www@c23d9e616cf9:/var/www$ ping -c5 host.docker.internal
PING host.docker.internal (172.17.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.203 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.108 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.111 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.107 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.112 ms
--- host.docker.internal ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.107/0.128/0.203/0.037 ms

Ping - ok
Then I try to call existing route in working Flask:
www@c23d9e616cf9:/var/www$ curl -X 'POST' http://host.docker.internal:5000/ping
curl: (7) Failed to connect to host.docker.internal port 5000 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server

What's wrong?

Is the Flask application listening on 0.0.0.0 or just localhost?

The canonical question for the problem @AKX suggests is Deploying a minimal flask app in docker - server connection issues.  If that's not your problem, can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Very low-level diagnostics around sending ICMP packets aren't that helpful, and from what you've described you probably don't need host.docker.internal; what does your source code and the rest of the Compose file look like?
